# Can we write a sql code with create function statements that all runs together at one time?

Tags: function, sql-server-2012

I have a piece of code (select and drop tables) where i use functions as well. 
But if run function with other codes, it says:-

> CREATE FUNCTION MUST BE THE ONLY STATEMENT IN THE BATCH

So can i only run the function code once and then remove it from the weekly job code (the creating and dropping of tables) ?
Or do i do something else.

This is one of the functions iam using:-

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getyrs(@parm Integer)
RETURNS INTEGER
AS
BEGIN
RETURN @parm
END;
```

But if i use drop function after this it gives an error (i can't run both drop and create functions together like i can run create and drop tables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you need to keep creating and dropping the function. Normally =you would create it once, and then call it for example like

```
SELECT schema.functionname(@paramatername)
```

Or you reference it in an outer apply or a create table etc

Comment: If i close the sql server management studio and open it again, the function needs to be created again. Probably because the function has a dbo in front of it, then maybe it is temporary?

Comment: It shouldn't need to be. It should be stored in the database and schema in which it was created?

Comment: dbo is the default schema for most databases unless specified otherwise. When you create a function, you can specify that it uses a certain database by running this code first `USE DatabaseName GO`, then create it on dbo.functionName and you should be able to keep calling it unless it ever gets dropped. Just make sure you use the USE statement to reference the correct database where the function is stored first before you run code to call it it

Comment: thanks bro! i think it worked. So i can simply use the function later without creating it over and over again.

Comment: No problem Abhay. Yeah that's the idea, they're for simplifying code blocks and making code reusable and easier to write.

Answer (score 1):

Put `GO` before the CREATE FUNCTION statement.

Also put it before any other statement that creates an object.

The `GO` statement signifies the start of a new `Batch` so any time you get an error about how a certain statement needs to be the first statement in a batch, or the only statement in a batch, you can use the `GO` statement to separate the code into batches.

This code works for me, no errors:

```
Go 

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getyrs(@parm Integer) 
RETURNS INTEGER 
AS 
BEGIN 
RETURN @parm 
END; 

GO 

DROP FUNCTION dbo.getyrs;
```

Comment: Go
    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getyrs(@parm Integer)
    RETURNS INTEGER
    AS
    BEGIN
    RETURN @parm
    END;
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.getyrs;                                                                                        If i run it all at once, it gives me an error :-                                               Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure getyrs, Line 7 [Batch Start Line 2]
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DROP'.

Comment: Put another `GO` before the DROP.